# Java call bash "su -c ... username" exit code 125

Tags: java, runtime, exec, su

I want to use rsync to backup files.
I use Java call shell like this

```
String cmd = "su -c \"rsync -avrco --progress /opt/tmp /opt/tmp2\" apache";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

but the p.waitFor()|p.exitValue() is 125.
why 125 ?

when the cmd is "su -c whoami", the p.waitFor()|p.exitValue() is 0. it is OK!

the full java test code is:

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String cmd = "su -c \"rsync -avrco --progress /opt/tmp /opt/tmp2\" apache";
    //      String cmd = "su -c whoami";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(p.waitFor());
            System.out.println(p.exitValue());
        }

    }
```

by the way, i have temp way to do it:

```
1.write cmd to file
2.use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh file");
it works well.
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are trying to execute this: `su -c "rsync -avrco --progress /opt/tmp /opt/tmp2" apache` using double quotes to delimit one parameter for **su**, but double quotes are understood by the shell, not by Java (that's why in your second case it works).

To make it work try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] cmd = new String[] {"su", "-c", "rsync -avrco --progress /opt/tmp /opt/tmp2", "apache"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(p.waitFor());
        System.out.println(p.exitValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: it works! thank you!<br>

i have seen this method<br>

    public Process exec(String command, String[] envp) throws IOException<br>
    envp - array of strings, each element of which has environment variable settings in the format name=value, or null if the subprocess should inherit the environment of the current process. <br>

but when i seen envp is name=value pair, the ‘apache’ only a value, so i give up!<br>